# What is the current way in which I can add an object to the database using Zend Framework?

Tags: php, database, zend-framework, zend-db

I want to save an object or form to the database. Only I can't find the easiest (or normal) way for how to do this.

I found a lot of tutorials, but none seem to be easy or current. Can someone please help me with this?

I use version 1.9.3 of the Zend Framework.

Comment: do you really mean 'object' and 'form' or do you mean the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way (aka the way using the smallest amount of code) to insert a row into a database table using [`Zend_Db`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html) is:

```
$data = array(
    'created_on'      => '2007-03-22',
    'bug_description' => 'Something wrong',
    'bug_status'      => 'NEW'
);

$db->insert('bugs', $data);
```

The above code will insert a new row into the `bugs` table whereas `$db` is the `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract`-subclass you created with `Zend_Db::factory()`. Please see [*Writing Changes to the Database*](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html#zend.db.adapter.write) in the [Zend Framework manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en) for more details and the whole spectrum of features `Zend_Db` provides.

For the sake of completeness, the above code will issue a query to the database similar to:

```
INSERT INTO bugs (created_on, bug_description, bug_status) 
    VALUES ('2007-03-22', 'Something wrong', 'NEW')
```

The next step would be a more sophisticated approach using [`Zend_Db_Table`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html).

**EDIT:**

Given that you have a `Zend_Form` (`$form`) with the appropriate fields `created_on`, `bug_description` and `bug_status` and provided that you have the right filters and validators in place, adding a new row with values given in the form is as easy as

```
if ($form->isValid($_POST)) {
    $db->insert('bugs', $form->getValues());
}
```

Storing a custom object is also very easy:

```
// $bug is your custom object representing a bug
$db->insert('bugs', array(
    'created_on'      => $bug->getCreatedOn(),
    'bug_description' => $bug->getDescription(),
    'bug_status'      => $bug->getStatus()
));
```

Comment: This clarification helps a lot. You are explaining it very well. Thanks for all of your time.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate any object that you need and [serialize it](http://www.php.net/serialize).  Once serialized, you can store it or transmit it to pretty much any medium.  Is this what you are referring to?